# Minimizing and eliminating a variable

Tags: inequality

We want to minimize
$$f(a,b,c)=-\frac{b(3b-4a+1)+a(a+5))}{(c+b+a)(a-1)}$$
subject to the constraints $0\le a\le b\le c\le 1$, and $a + b + c = p$ for $p\in\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right]$.

How can we prove that, for all $p\in\left[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right]$, the minimum is attained when $b=c$ ?

Comment: Please check the numerator ($+b$ twice)? Also check the last word $b=d$?

Comment: @RiverLi you are right, I have been confused because I am working on several similar inequalities at the same time.

Comment: Please check $p=2$, $a=0, b = 0, c = 2$ (the denominator $a+2b=0$).

Comment: @RiverLi I corrected the formulas. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to suppose that you have a feasible solution with $b < c$ and perturb the solution to $b+\epsilon$ and $c-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon \in (0,(c-b)/2]$.  This perturbation preserves feasibility, so if you can show that $f(a,b,c)>f(a,b+\epsilon,c-\epsilon)$, you are done.

Comment: Thank you @RobPratt ! Is this condition also necessary (taking into account the function of the question) besides being sufficient to prove the result?